# Не могу разместить содержимое футера в одну строку

Tags: css

```css
footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FAFAFB;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 58px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span class="txt">Ответим на вопросы &#8212; <a href="mailto:123@123.ru">123@123.ru</a>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
      <select name="list1"> 
        <option>ИСХОДЯЩИЙ ВЫЗОВ</option>
        <option>ВХОДЯЩИЙ ВЫЗОВ</option>
        <option>ИСХОДЯЩЕЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ</option>
        <option>ВХОДЯЩЕЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ</option>
        <option>ВСТРЕЧА</option>
        <option>СОБЫТИЕ</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" class="subm" name="submit" value="ЗАПЛАНИРОВАТЬ">
    </form>
  </span>
</footer>
```

[image: footer]

Ну никак не хочет в одну строчку располагаться

Comment: @UModeL дал правильный ответ. Но всё-таки не стоит помещать блочный элемент `<form>` в  строчный `<span>`.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров спора нет. Просто, раз человек так сверстал, то здесь, чувствую, долго объяснять нужно, а я с работы торопился убежать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более современный вариант (с inline-block, например, можно долго выравнивать блоки, и всё равно они не будут находиться по центру по высоте. А с line-height при таком использовании можно в будущем вообще попасть в 9 круг ада):

```css
footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #FAFAFB;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
footer > .txt {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span class="txt">Ответим на вопросы &#8212; <a href="mailto:123@123.ru">123@123.ru</a>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
      <select name="list1">
        <option>ИСХОДЯЩИЙ ВЫЗОВ</option>
        <option>ВХОДЯЩИЙ ВЫЗОВ</option>
        <option>ИСХОДЯЩЕЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ</option>
        <option>ВХОДЯЩЕЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ</option>
        <option>ВСТРЕЧА</option>
        <option>СОБЫТИЕ</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" class="subm" name="submit" value="ЗАПЛАНИРОВАТЬ">
    </form>
  </span>
</footer>
```